# How to close snackbar on click of close buttton?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to close snackbar on click on close button.
Initially, on page load snackbar should popup by default and it should remain until I close it manually. So, I set timeout to zero.But my snackbar is not getting closed on click of close button. Require you input.

HTML templete

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
     <v-snackbar
        class="regiSnack"
        :timeout="0"
        :value="true"
        absolute
        :multi-line="multiLine"
        top
        color="deep-purple accent-4"
        elevation="50"
        >
          This is Snackbar
          <template >
             <v-btn text @click="snackbar: false"> Close </v-btn>
         </template>
     </v-snackbar>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS -

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
     
      snackbar: true,
     
    }
  },
})
```

https://codepen.io/KiranGire/pen/eYjBpOP?editors=101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first. What kind of assignment operator looks like this-

```
@click="snackbar: false"
```

If you want to assign a value to any variable, you must use `=` operator. So replace the above code with this-

```
@click="snackbar = false"
```

Second thing, if you will use `:value="true"` then obviously the snackbar will be displayed forever. So, bind the `value prop` to the variable which you are using to toggle the snackbar instead of a hard-coded boolean. For example-

```
:value="snackbar"
```

Do these two fixes, and it will work.

Comment: Above solution works. Thanks! Also I want to ask what is difference between :value and v-model?

Comment: Give a read to this- https://learnvue.co/tutorials/v-model-guide

Comment: If I want that snackbar to be visible after 2 mins after closing. Here is what I have added https://codepen.io/KiranGire/pen/eYjBpOP?editors=1010 but in that case it is not getting closed.

Comment: I have written the code and it is working fine. But I want to reduce lines of code. I have to write same code multiple times to display snackbar after closing after 2 mins. Can you suggest any improvement? You can refer above link to refer code

Comment: You can create a common function to display the snackbar. See this- https://codepen.io/nehasoni988/pen/mdjOqwR

Answer (score 0):

you can use the next code:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">
  <v-card>
    <v-snackbar
      class="regiSnack"
      :timeout="0"
      :value="snackbar"
      absolute
      :multi-line="multiLine"
      top
      color="deep-purple accent-4"
      elevation="50"
    >
      This is Snackbar
      <template>
        <v-btn text @click="snackbar = false"> Close </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-snackbar>
   </v-card>
  </v-app>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return {
    snackbar: true,
   }
  },
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assignment issue was the thing, snackbar:false has to be changed to snackbar = false

<v-btn text @click="snackbar = false"> Close

Comment: Thank you for input but if I add "this" keyword then snackbar is not getting loaded. https://codepen.io/KiranGire/pen/eYjBpOP?editors=101 -> added "this" keyword and checked not working

Comment: `snackbar: false` is not a valid assignment operation.